# Clong overflow in VB6

Tags: vb6, types

I'm having an overflow error in VB 6.0 when using the `Clong` datatype because of really big values.  How to overcome this?  Is there anything else available higher than the `Clong` datatype?

Answer (score 5):

You could use a **Double** instead of a Long since it can hold larger numbers. The function is CDbl() instead CLng().

In VB6.0, a Long is 32-bits and can hold values up to: 2,147,483,648
A Double is 64-bits and can old values up to: 1.79769313486231570E+308

**EDIT:** Please refer to this [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420(VS.60).aspx)

Comment: Be careful! A double doesn't actually hold more precision, though it can hold larger numbers. Doubles on most systems are rounded to somewhere around 15 digts. For example, 123456789012345678901234567890 will become 1.2345678901234568e29.

Comment: Curt is basically right. Although a Double _does_ have more precision than a Long, of course: a Long has 10 significant figures and a Double has 15 or 16. And, Jose, why not link to the VB6 reference manual? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420(VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how big your really big values are, the VB6 Currency data type might be a good choice.

It supports values in the range -922,337,203,685,477.5808 to 922,337,203,685,477.5807.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the upcoming VB in MSVS2010 has the `CLonger` (64 bits), `CEvenLongerYet` (128 bits) and `CTooDamnLongForSensibleUse` (256 bits) data types.

</humor>

Comment: For a minute there, I thought you were being serious... LOL

Comment: I'm curious, José. Which of the three data types actually convinced you I wasn't being serious? I would hope it wasn't the CTooDamnLongForSensibleUse one :-) Or worse yet, the closing humor tag :-)

Comment: Actually there's going to be a CEvenLongerThanCTooDamnLongForSensibleUse type aka BigInteger in .NET 4.0: http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2007/01/16/introducing-system-numeric-biginteger-inbar-gazit.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options from the VB6 reference manual [topic on data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420(VS.60).aspx)

- Long (long integer) 4 bytes
  -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
- Single (single-precision
  floating-point) 4 bytes -3.402823E38
  to -1.401298E-45 for negative values;
  1.401298E-45 to 3.402823E38 for positive values. About 6 or 7 significant figures accuracy.
- Double
  (double-precision floating-point) 8
  bytes -1.79769313486231E308 to 
  -4.94065645841247E-324 for negative values; 4.94065645841247E-324 to
  1.79769313486232E308 for positive values. About 15 or 16 significant figures accuracy.
- Currency (scaled integer) 8
  bytes -922,337,203,685,477.5808 to
  922,337,203,685,477.5807
- Decimal 14
  bytes
  +/-79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335
  with no decimal point; 
  +/-7.9228162514264337593543950335 with 28 places to the right of the
  decimal; smallest non-zero number is 
  +/-0.0000000000000000000000000001

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding division by zero. If the numerator and denominator object of your code is equal to zero, try making the denominator equal to 1. hence, zero/zero = overflow
         zero/1 = zero ( no overflow)