# VB datatypes size

Tags: vb6

In VB 6,is there any way to get the variable size greater than Long?
I have to display the data which is exceeding the size of Long on the same page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Currency` data type.

It is 8 bytes and supports values in the range -922,337,203,685,477.5808 to 922,337,203,685,477.5807.

[VBA Datatype Summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420%28VS.60%29.aspx)

Answer (score 12):

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909103/clong-overflow-in-vb6) on VB6 data types. Here are some options from the VB6 manual [topic on data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420(VS.60).aspx)

| Type | Description | Size | Min | Max | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Long** | Long Integer | 4 bytes | -2,147,483,648 | 2,147,483,647 |  |
| **Single** | Single-precision floating-point | 4 bytes | -3.402823E38 (negative values) 1.401298E-45 (positive values) | -1.401298E-45 (negative values) 3.402823E38 (positive values) | About 6 or 7 significant figures accuracy. |
| **Double** | Double-precision floating-point | 8 bytes | -1.79769313486231E308 (negative values) 4.94065645841247E-324 (positive values) | -4.94065645841247E-324 (negative values) 1.79769313486232E308 (positive values) | About 15 or 16 significant figures accuracy. |
| **Currency** | Scaled integer | 8 bytes | -922,337,203,685,477.5808 | 922,337,203,685,477.5807 |  |
| **Decimal** |  | 14 bytes | +/- 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335 (no decimal point) | +/- 7.9228162514264337593543950335 (with 28 places to the right of the decimal) | Smallest non-zero number is +/-0.0000000000000000000000000001 |

Comment: This is only valid for VBA

Comment: It's valid for VBA and vb6. I know it says VBA at the top of the page. But the languages are 99% identical & microsoft only provide VBA versions of some topics.

Comment: Decimal is not valid in VB6. Only VBA.