# Dll imported functions not working on C# but do on vb6

Tags: c#, .net, dll, vb6, dllimport

I'm using an old dll file function that is currently working ok in vb6, declared like this:

```
Public Declare Function DecOutb Lib "DecLib.dll" Alias "_outportb@8" _
(ByVal PortAddress As Long, ByVal state As Byte) As Long

Public Declare Function DecOutLong Lib "DecLib.dll" Alias "_outport@8" _
(ByVal PortAddress As Long, ByVal state As Long) As Long
```

The implementation of the funcion is this:

```
k = DecOutLong(ad_addr, Data)
```

It returns k=1 when it is successful, and it is.

However when I put this on my .net C#, even if I don't get any warning or error, but the function does not work, returning k=0.  The declaration I'm making is like this:

```
[DllImport("DecLib.dll", EntryPoint = "_outport@8", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int DecOutLong(int PortAddress, int State);
```

And the implementation is this:

```
k = DecOutLong(ad_addr, DATA);
```

Comment: In VB6 return type is long and parameters are either long or byte

Comment: Sorry, dismiss the first VB6 declaration, the example is for the second one, although none works

Comment: ^ this. the equivalent of VB6 [long is Int32](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1253733/1132334), and Byte should be `byte`.

Comment: I'm using int and byte  for long and byte, and int is int32

Comment: Have you tried changing the calling convention to `CallingConvention.Cdecl`?  This may not work, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Your C# matches the VB

Comment: when it succeeds from the VB6 code, is this on the same OS on the same machine?
outport and outportb are functions that assign a value to a (hardware) port so returning the value for "failure" does not necessarily mean that the call from managed to unmanaged code is the problem

Comment: Chris Dunham... When I use CallingConvention.Cdecl  I get "A call to PInvoke function 'WindowsFormsApp1!WindowsFormsApp1.Form1::DecOutLong' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged"

Comment: dlatikay, yes, it is the same OS, same machine, both for compiling and running, IDEs are VS2015 and VB6 respectively, I've also verified that I'm sending the same parameters to the function on both cases.

Comment: It's stdcall. Why would you think it was cdecl. No point guessing. There's nothing wrong with the pinvoke. It is correct. Whatever the issue is, it cannot be determined from the information here.

Comment: Please try compiling your .NET application explicitly as x86 and see if that addresses your issue.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED, I followed tcarvin's advice and set it to compile to x86 instead of "Any PC". I'm suspecting there is more to clarify in this situation, but at least it works.