# VBA Code: How would you count even numbers and add them together

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

- I ask the user to put an input number like a "max" and then count and add all the even numbers together. For example: If the user inputs 6 then that would be 2+4+6 = 12

```
Sub AddupEvenNumbers()
    Dim num As Variant
    Dim evennum As Variant
    Dim sum As Double
    Dim str As String
    Dim count As Integer
    
    str = "Enter a upper/maximum number "
    num = InputBox(str)
    evennum = num
    
    If num Mod 2 Then
        evennum = num.Value + num
        count = count + 1
    End If
    MsgBox "The sum of even numbers " & vbNewLine & "from 0 to " & num & vbNewLine & "is " & evennum

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to loop using a For loop and step 2:

```
Sub AddupEvenNumbers()
    Dim num As Variant
    Dim evennum As Long
    Dim sum As Double
    Dim str As String
    Dim count As Integer
    
    str = "Enter a upper/maximum number "
    Do
        num = InputBox(str)
        If Not IsNumeric(num) Then str = "Must be a number." & vbNewLine & "Enter a upper/maximum number "
    Loop While Not IsNumeric(num)

    sum = 0

    For evennum = 0 To num Step 2
        sum = sum + evennum
    Next evennum
    
    MsgBox "The sum of even numbers " & vbNewLine & "from 0 to " & num & vbNewLine & "is " & sum

End Sub
```

Or use [`Application.InputBox(str,Type:= 1)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) to force a numeric entry

```
Sub AddupEvenNumbers()
    Dim num As Double
    Dim evennum As Long
    Dim sum As Double
    Dim str As String
    Dim count As Integer
    
    str = "Enter a upper/maximum number "

    num = Application.InputBox(str, Type:=1)
    
    sum = 0

    For evennum = 0 To num Step 2
        sum = sum + evennum
    Next evennum
    
    MsgBox "The sum of even numbers " & vbNewLine & "from 0 to " & num & vbNewLine & "is " & sum

End Sub
```

Comment: But what does that type:=1 do again

Comment: Check the link I added in my latest edit, it gives the full list.  But type 1 will only allow the entry of a number so the user cannot "accidentally" enter a text string. @MattFlower

Comment: The calculation could be simplified considerably to just be `(num / 2 + 1) * num/ 2`

Comment: @pgSystemTester yes.  I went with the assumption that the OP was asking a general question to learn more about looping in vba and not the specific on how to find the sum of all even numbers from 0 to a given value.  But if that really is the end result of this question then your question is better.

Comment: @ScottCraner how would implement a minimum value. for example, if the user enters: (4 22) thus the min will be 4 and the max 22 and finding the even numbers and adding them?

Comment: The best would be to use two separate input boxes, one asking for the min and the other for the max.  You would need to check to ensure that the min is a even number to start.  Then change the `For` statement, but replacing the `0` with the min variable. @MattFlower  Try to do that on your own and if you get stuck ask a new question.

Comment: @ScottCraner makes sense. I didn't read much past the title..

Comment: @ScottCraner here is where I am at so far but I am struggling:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74142004/vba-code-how-would-you-count-even-numbers-and-add-them-up-based-off-of-a-single?noredirect=1#comment130906273_74142004

Answer (score 3):

No need for VBA. You can use a formula:
With the entered number in A1:

```
=SUM(SEQUENCE(A1)*ISEVEN(SEQUENCE(A1)))
```

In earlier versions of Excel, you can use an array-formula:

```
=SUM(ISEVEN(ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,A1)))*ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,A1)))
```

*In some earlier versions of Excel, you may need to "confirm" this **array-formula** by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar*

Comment: Yeah but using an vba input box the user must input a value then there will be an output msgbox with the answer

Comment: `=SUM(SEQUENCE(INT(A1/2),,2,2))`

Comment: You can leverage the fact that all the numbers being added together are essentially pairs that will equal to the original number (i.e. 6+0 = 6, 4+2=6.. etc), making a much simpler formula of `=(num/2+1)*num/2` in VBA or Excel.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your question *how to count even numbers less than a number* (presumably over zero):

```
num / 2 + 1
```

To answer to *how to sum these numbers*: we know that opposite pairs of these values will sum to the original value (so for 6.... `4,2 = 6`. So the number of pairs is half of the count from the previous calculation, multiplied by the `num` value.

```
(num / 2 + 1) / 2 * num
```

Combined with your implied question about handling user errors, see code below for a suggested route I might use. Note I never use `mod` to test if somethign is even due to the fact that it forces the value to convert to a `Long` (see my Stack Overflow [debut question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44987908/mod-function-exclusively-uses-long-variables-in-excel-vba) on that topic... as it WILL error out if number is too big). So I use an `int` comparison shown below which also rejects decimals.

```
Sub ExampeEntry()
Dim aResponse As String, aNumberResponse As Long
       
start:
    aResponse = Replace(InputBox("Enter An Even Number"), ",", "") 'or "." if Europe
        
    If aResponse = "" Then
        'User cancelled/didn't enter
    ElseIf IsNumeric(aResponse) Then
        If Int(aResponse / 2) <> aResponse / 2 Then
            MsgBox aResponse & " is not an even number..."
            GoTo start
        Else
            'success
            aNumberResponse = aResponse
            MsgBox (aNumberResponse / 2 + 1)/2 * aNumberResponse
        End If
        
    Else
        MsgBox "ummm... """ & aResponse & """ isn't a number my friend...", vbCritical, "oh boy..."
        GoTo start
    End If
        
End Sub
```